# GWCLI Not Working After Deleting Pool in Ceph

Tags: ceph

I have ovirt running on some VM Hosts alongside my storage running Ceph. Recently I ran into an issue on ovirt that had me recreate the VM storage as a new pool and delete the old pool.

Today, I needed to expand the storage of my media and gwcli came back with

```
ObjectNotFound: [errno 2] RADOS object not found (error opening pool 'vm_pool')
```

Away to google I went, and the only instruction I could find was to wipe out the gateway.conf and rebuild with:

```
rados -p rbd rm gateway.conf
```

Thinking quickly but not safely, I did just that. Then it dawned on me I should have saved that file first. Not to worry, I can rebuild my gateway from memory; it wasn't that much and ovirt has the little details stored.

Except any time I try to create anything in gwcli, it kicks me out with an error akin to:

```
KeyError: 'pool'
```

or

```
KeyError: 'iqn.1994-05.com.redhat:ovirt'
```

That's all it tells me. I wipe out my gateway.conf again and it lets me back in, but anything I do this happens.

Two main questions, since I'm here.

- How exactly do I get gwcli back up and playing nice?
- Even if I get it playing nice... how do I map the gateway to the existing images stored in the pools? It's only just now dawning on me that adding an iscsi disk may not link to the old image. Please tell me the data is accessible, that's like 30TB of data...

**EDIT:** GWCLI is actually working fine, the issue is I cannot feed it data that already exists.  For instance, if I create a target using the old data, it will fail.  If I create a target with new data, it works fine.

So if there is just a way to map it to the old data I should be set; any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a, probably wrong way, solution to the problem.

Let me start from the beginning.  **IF** you deleted a pool from Ceph without first removing it from your iscsi gateway, you will need to *modify* your gateway.conf.  To do so, run:

```
rados -p rbd get gateway.conf ~/gateway.conf.edit
```

Edit the file to remove the disk from each host and from disks.  Then run:

```
rados -p rbd put gateway.conf ~/gateway.conf.edit
```

Once done, restart the rbd-target-gw and rbd-target-api services and move along, gwcli should be working.

**IF you are like me, and decided to mess this up and just wipe out the gateway.conf**

Go into gwcli and create a new target.  Yes, a new one with a new name.  It cannot be the old name.  Set the gateways, add your hosts, and give them the authentication you need.

Now, go into /disks and re-add your disks with a new image name.  For example, one of my disks was vm_data_pool/vm_data_pool.  Since gwcli goes ape when I try to add with the old name, I had to add vm_data_pool/vm_data_pool-test.  Give it something small like 1G:

```
disk add vm_data_pool-test vm_data_pool 1G
```

Exit gwcli and download the fresh gateway.conf:

```
rados -p rbd get gateway.conf ~/gateway.conf.edit
```

Find the "disks" entry, locate your disk, and modify everywhere with the image name.  This will be the disk entry itself, the backstore_object_name, and the image.  You will also need to modify the wwn to match the old value.

Save and apply your new config:

```
rados -p rbd put gateway.conf ~/gateway.conf.edit
```

Restart the rbd-target-gw and rbd-target-api services and re-enter gwcli.  In /disks run an ls and you will see the sizes have updated to the old storage size.  Add the disks to your hosts under the target and point the old host back to the new iscsi iqn.

Comment: This works for us and I'm not aware of anything else. It is easy for the `gateway.conf` to become invalid (e.g. by RBD images being removed or renamed) and the iSCSI gateway serviced won't notice until it is restarted. This is one of many reasons why I consider iSCSI for Ceph immature. You should probably install a monitoring service that continually runs `gwcli` and sets off an alarm when it fails.